# MongooseError: `Model.create()` cannot run without a model as `this`. Make sure you are not calling `new Model.create()`

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

soy nuevo en mongo y mongoose, tengo un modelo con mongoose y al momento de llamarlo me está arrojando este error:
MongooseError: `Model.create()` cannot run without a model as `this`. Make sure you are not calling `new Model.create()`

el modelo es super simple:

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";
const rolesSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name:String,
  
  },
  { versionKey: false}
);
export default model ('roles', rolesSchema);
```

lo que hago es inicializar unos valores el momento de ejecutar la app cargando la librería initialSetup

```
 import Roles from "../models/roles";
    export const createRoles = async () => {
          const cantidad = await roles.estimatedDocumentCount(); //cantidad estimada de documentos (objetos) en la coleccion
if (cantidad > 0) return;
    
    const valores = await Promise.all([
      // ejecuta todas las promises al mismo tiempo
      new roles.create({ name: "usuario" }).save(), //crea un rol de tipo usuario en la coleccion de roles
      new roles.create({ name: "admnistrador" }).save(), //crea un rol de tipo administrador en la coleccion de roles
      new roles.create({ name: "moderador" }).save(), //crea un rol de tipo moderador en la coleccion de roles por las dudas haga falta mas adelante
    
  ]);
    };
```

en el app.js lo llamo así;

```
import express from 'express';
import methodOverride from 'method-override';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import './database';
import {createRoles} from './libs/initialSetup';
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
createRoles();
```

Alguna idea del motivo por el cual podría estar dandome este error?.

Comment: Lo que veo es que haces: `import Roles`, pero luego lo usas en minúsculas: `await roles.estimatedDocumentCount();` y `new roles.create({ ... })`. Además, un modelo de datos debería entenderse como *una* entidad. Pienso que el nombre apropiado al modelo debería ser *Rol*, y no *Roles*. La colección sí puede llamarse *roles*. Al fin y al cabo cada vez que creas un documento de tipo *Rol* es un sólo tipo de *Rol* y no muchos. Semánticamente hablando sería lo preferible. Saludos

Comment: Por otro lado, el uso de `roles.create()` no es compatible con el constructor `new` ni con el método `save`, en todo caso has de hacerlo como `roles.create({ ... })` (sin anteponer `new` ni usar `save`) o con `(new roles({ ... })).save()` (observa que encierro `new roles( ... )` entre paréntesis antes de llamar a `save()` y no uso `create`). Y dado que estás trabajando con Promesas te falta el `await` antes de cada llamada a `save()` o `create()`, por ejemplo: `await (new roles({ name: 'user'})).save();`. De esta forma no necesitas `Promise.all`. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Tal como digo en mis [comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/555942/mongooseerror-model-create-cannot-run-without-a-model-as-this-make-sure/555973#comment982394_555942), hay un problema de semántica (según mi punto de vista) y un problema en el uso del constructor (`new`) y el método `create`. Además, el método `create` crea y guarda el documento en base de datos, sin necesidad de usar `save`.

Además, el uso de `Promise.all` no estaría justificado ya que estás usando una función asíncrona para crear tus roles.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Lo primero es cambiar el nombre del modelo por algo más apropiado semánticamente. Por lo cual el modelo debería quedar así:

```js
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";
const RolSchema = new Schema(  // <= nombre del esquema en singular y primera letra mayúscula
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,  // podemos ser más específicos al declarar el esquema
    }
  },
  { versionKey: false}
);
export default model('Rol', rolesSchema); // <= el nombre del modelo con la primera letra mayúscula y en singular
```

Luego lo usaremos así:

```js
import Rol from "../models/rol"; // <= nombre del archivo compatible con el modelo

export const initRoles = async () => {  // <= nombre del método refleja la acción
  const rolesExistentes = await Rol.estimatedDocumentCount(); //cantidad estimada de documentos (objetos) en la coleccion
  if (rolesExistentes > 0) return;
    
  const roles = [
    await (new Rol({ name: "usuario" })).save(),
    await (new Rol({ name: "admnistrador" })).save(),
    await (new Rol({ name: "moderador" })).save(),
  ];
  return roles;  // si no necesitamos devolver esto, entonces no hace falta el Array
};
```

Como se observa no usaremos `Promises.all` para nada, ya que estamos dentro de una función `async`y podemos usar `await`directamente.

Otra forma de hacerlo con `create` y si no necesitamos devolver el resultado del proceso de `init` sería:

```js
import Rol from "../models/rol"; // <= nombre del archivo compatible con el modelo

export const initRoles = async () => {  // <= nombre del método refleja la acción
  const rolesExistentes = await Rol.estimatedDocumentCount(); //cantidad estimada de documentos (objetos) en la coleccion
  if (rolesExistentes > 0) return;
  try {  
    await Rol.create({ name: "usuario" });
    await Rol.create({ name: "admnistrador" });
    await Rol.create({ name: "moderador" });
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(`Error al crear roles: ${e.message}`);
  }
};
```

Es muy importante al trabajar con procesos asíncronos y Promesas, usar bloques `try ... catch`.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

**EDICIÓN**

En tu comentario a mi respuesta dices que el nombre de la colección en base de datos ha cambiado. Es una característica de Mongoose, que intenta convertir en plurarl el nombre del modelo para crear la colección. Sin embargo, puedes establecer manuealment el nombre de la colección al momento de crear el esquema, usando la opción `collection` y asignándole el nombre que consideres adecuado. Por ejemplo:

```js
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";
const RolSchema = new Schema(  // <= nombre del esquema en singular y primera letra mayúscula
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,  // podemos ser más específicos al declarar el esquema
    }
  },
  { versionKey: false, collection: 'roles'}  // <= establezco el nombre de la colección
);
export default model('Rol', rolesSchema); // <= el nombre del modelo con la primera letra mayúscula y en singular
```

Comment: Hola Mauricio, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Si tenia pueso el try catch pero lo saque mientras iba probando algunas cosas. No me quedó muy claro por que me creo una coleccion llamada "Rols" ahora en la db. Lo hizo porque el modelo se llama "Rol"?. Antes se llamaba roles. Lo del Promises.all tengo entendido que es un beneficio ya que hace paralelamente todas las inserciones.

Comment: Editaré la respuesta. sobre el nombre de la colección.

Comment: excelente! Muchas gracias Mauricio